# Joining 3 tables in sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, join

I have three tables in sql-server like table A table B table C.

How can I join 3 tables as expressed in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Explain how to read the diagram. If it's a Venn diagram, what are the circles sets of & why are they labelled that way & what does it have to do with joining--especially since tables are bags of rows not sets of rows & we can expect no row value of any of those tables to be in any other table? (Venn diagrams are frequently given to allegedly illustrate joins, but they are never explained & almost never make sense. But here you need to make sense if you want to have asked a question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More information needed to give you a correct piece of code, but from the image you need [LEFT JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join)s.

*(ID's have been presumed)*

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Items i ON c.iid = i.id
LEFT JOIN Sales s ON c.sid = s.id
```

Comment: I think your code is 90% correct, but you would not return items the items that are matched between ITEMS & SALES. There is an inner join needed between Items and Sales to add that one area.

Answer (score -1):

It's never too late :)

Most probably you'll need this:

```
select ...
  from customers
  full outer join (items inner join sales on (xxx)) on (xxx)
```